# Questions regarding my OpenGL - code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, buffer, opengl-es-2.0

I have been starting to dive into OpenGL ES 2.0 the last couple days, but I still get really faulty results. One thing I do not quite understand, is how I am supposed to set up my buffers correctly.

I would like to create a shape like this: A kind of tent, if you like, without the left and right side.

```
3_______________________2
|\                     /|
| \_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _/ |          
| /4                 5\ |
|/_____________________\|
0                       1
```

So let's start with my Texture/Indices/Vertices Array:

**That is what i set up :**

```
#define RECT_TOP_R      {1, 1, 0}
#define RECT_TOP_L      {-1, 1, 0}
#define RECT_BOTTOM_R   {1, -1, 0}
#define RECT_BOTTOM_L   {-1, -1, 0}
#define BACK_RIGHT      {1, 0, -1.73}
#define BACK_LEFT       {-1, 0, -1.73}

const GLKVector3 Vertices[] = {
    RECT_BOTTOM_L,  //0
    RECT_BOTTOM_R,  //1
    RECT_TOP_R,     //2
    RECT_TOP_L,     //3
    BACK_LEFT,      //4
    BACK_RIGHT      //5

};

const GLKVector4 Color[] = {
    {1,0,0,1},
    {0,1,0,1},
    {0,0,1,1},
    {0,1,0,1},
    {1,0,0,1},
    {0,1,0,1},
    {0,0,1,1},
    {0,1,0,1}
};

const GLubyte Indices[] = {
    0,1,3,
    2,4,5,
    0,1
};

const GLfloat texCoords[] = {
    0,0,
    1,0,
    0,1,
    1,1,
    1,1,
    0,0,
    0,0,
    1,0
};
```

**Here I generate/bind the buffers.**

```
glGenBuffers(1, &vertexArray);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexArray);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,sizeof(Vertices),0);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertices), Vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glGenBuffers(1, &indexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Indices), Indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


glGenBuffers(1, &colArray);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribColor);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribColor, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Color), 0);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Color), Color, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glGenBuffers(1, &texArray);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(texCoords),0);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(texCoords), texCoords, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

So I have a questions regarding buffers:

- What is the difference between GL_ARRAY_BUFFER and GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER ?

**Here is the gelegate method, which is called whenever it redraws:**

```
- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect {


    self.contentScaleFactor = 2.0;
    self.opaque = NO;

    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    [self.effect prepareToDraw];

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, sizeof(Indices), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);


}
```

So, the code obviously does not work accordingly. Could you please help me ? I have been trying to get it to work, but I am losing my nerves.

Comment: Got it, forgot to bind the buffers. *facepalm*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I definitely did something wrong there. I reused code from a website which basically stored all the Vertex data in one struct. I, however, have changed the code, in that I have separated the individual attribute arrays (colors, texture coordinates) into individual arrays. Before, the struct was buffered on its own, so the struct was processed by the GPU as a whole with the texture array and the color array. Now - after my changes - I need to generate and bind those buffers individually.

Another problem I could partly resolve was the one with the indices and texture mapping. I do not know whether I understood that right, but if I assign the texture coordinates (x,y) to a certain index and then reuse that index - with the aim of having another texture coordinate in that exact place - then apparently I would not have reason to wonder why everything is messed up.

What I ended up doing did not exactly solve my problem, but I got a whole lot nearer to my set goal and I am quite proud of my learning curve so far as far as openGL is concerned. 
This answer is intended for others who might face the same problems and I hope that I do not spread any wrong information here. Please feel free to edit/point out any mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

In response to your own answer, the vertex data in a struct you mentioned is called a struct of arrays. Apple recommend you use this [layout](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH107-SW10).